# JSON data is not coming properly on webpage

Tags: php, html, json

here is my Data on the console it is showing properly

```
ResponseText {
    "user":
    {
        "userId":"1",
        "userName":"Khizer",
        "profile_Img":"Khizar.jpg"
    },
    "comment": {
            "comment_id":21,
            "comment":"checking 9",
            "userId":1
            },
    "error":false
}
```

but its not coming on the web page
in comment box in place of name it is showing "undefined"
and in place of comment text it is showing "[object Object]"

here is my code to print it on webpage

```
function comment_insert(data)
{
  var t = '';
  t += '<li class="comment-holder" id="_'+data.comment.comment_id+'">';
  t += '<div class="user-img">';
  t += '<img src="'+data.user.profile_Img+'" class="user-img-pic"/>';
  t += '</div>';
  t += '<div class="comment-body">';
  t += '<h3 class="username-feild">'+data.user.userName+'</h3>';
  t += '<div class="comment-text">'+data.comment.comment+'</div>';
  t +=  '</div>';
  t +=  '<div class="comment-buttons-holder">';
  t += '<ul>';
  t +=   '<li class="delete-btn">';
  t +=          'X';
  t +=   '</li>';
  t +='</ul>';
  t +='</div>';
  t +='</li>';
  $('.comment-holder-ul').prepend(t);
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to make `data.user.profile_Img` feasible, `data` should be an object first: `data` should be parsed as JSON Object first.

```
jsonData = JSON.parse(data)
```

Then you will be able to visit data by `dataObj.user.profile_Img` or other keys in the object.

[Edit] Test Code for your example:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="test">
</div>
</body>
<script>
var data = JSON.parse('{"user":{"userId":"1","userName":"Khizer","profile_Img":"Khizar.jpg"},"comment":{"comment_id":21,"comment":"checking9","userId":1},"error":false}')
function comment_insert(data)
{
  var t = '';
  t += '<li class="comment-holder" id="_'+data.comment.comment_id+'">';
  t += '<div class="user-img">';
  t += '<img src="'+data.user.profile_Img+'" class="user-img-pic"/>';
  t += '</div>';
  t += '<div class="comment-body">';
  t += '<h3 class="username-feild">'+data.user.userName+'</h3>';
  t += '<div class="comment-text">'+data.comment.comment+'</div>';
  t +=  '</div>';
  t +=  '<div class="comment-buttons-holder">';
  t += '<ul>';
  t +=   '<li class="delete-btn">';
  t +=          'X';
  t +=   '</li>';
  t +='</ul>';
  t +='</div>';
  t +='</li>';
  return t;
}
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = comment_insert(data)
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: i am using this statement to pass data 
comment_insert(jQuery.parseJSON(data));"

Comment: There must be some problem of your data processing. You can print the data object (parsed) into the console and see what happened. If it is correct, you should see several objects. I edited my answer and pasted the test code for your example, it works well on my browser.